# What does "TypeError: 'generator' object does not support item assignment" mean?

Tags: python, pandas, date

When I try to run the following code I get an error called: `TypeError: 'generator' object does not support item assignment`. How can I fix this?

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd
import re
import sys

path = r'C:\Users\Nicole\02_Datenverarbeitung und Analyse\Input'            

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "scrapeddata*.csv"))

for files in all_files:
    basic_file_name = files.replace(path, '')
    date = basic_file_name[13:22]

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', encoding='iso-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False) for f in all_files)
df_from_each_file['date'] = 'date'

df_merged = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
df_merged
```

Comment: `df_from_each_file`, despite the name, isn't a data frame - it's a generator, created using a _generator expression_ `value for item in iterable`.

Comment: You want to add a column to every DF ?

Comment: How can I change it to a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a column to every DF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
...
# Use brackets instead of parenthesis
df_from_each_file = [
    pd.read_csv(
        f, sep=",", encoding="iso-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False
    )
    for f in all_files
]

# Assign new column to each df
for df in df_from_each_file:
    df["date"] = "date"

# Concat dataframes
df_merged = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```